# Find Column With Max on Other Column Grouping By Another Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
Id   - ItemId -  Price   -  SalesId       -       Date
1       12      99.99924    21899234        2025-01-01 00:00:00.000000
2       123     12.34567    348923          2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000
3       1234    1234.5      3321234         2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000
4       12345   3.3246      2154234         2023-01-01 00:00:00.000000
5       1234    451.234     3423            2020-02-01 00:00:00.000000
6       12345   0.989       71112357        2020-09-15 20:20.10.000000
7       123     3435.3      71112357        2020-09-14 20:10:12.000000
```

I am trying to find the `Price` of an `Item` with latest `Date`. For example, if we tried to find `ItemId = 1234`, the one with the latest date is this `2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000` that has `Id = 3`, it has the price of 1234.5. That's what I'm trying to find by this query, the price of this item.

I am a beginner to SQL and tried the following query, but it gives me this error:

```
select "ItemId",
       max("Date"),
       "Price"
from "Products"
group by "ItemId"
```

> [42803] ERROR: column "Products.Price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I appreciate any help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on ("ItemId") p.*
from "Products" p
order by "ItemId", "Date" desc;
```

Note:  If you are learning SQL, don't use double quotes for string and column names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon, but it gives me this error: *[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "desc"* in a PostgreSQL database. I am using DataGrip.

Comment: If I remove the `desc`, it gives me a different error: *[42803] ERROR: column "p.Id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*.

Comment: @N.Dogac change `group by` to `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select ItemId,Date,Price,row_number() over(partition by itemid order by date desc) as rn
from Products
)A where rn=1
```